# Core-Plot region as part of View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

The dilemma below seems like a very easy problem to overcome, yet I can't find anything about how to tackle it.  I've checked various tutorials, as well as all the sample code bundled with Core-Plot.

I've recently set up a new iPhone view-based application. However, I don't want the graph to take up the whole screen/view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a UIView inside your main UIView. Then change the type of that inner view to the UIView subclass that you need, such as CPGraphHostingView.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How would I then reference that from the code, though?  I guess my question is, how do I actually tell the code to put the graph in that smaller region within the main view?

Comment: Make an IBOutlet in your view controller and connect the graph view to it. Then you can configure the graph as necessary when you load it.